# Authorize users w.r.t assigned groups in ITIM

Tags: java, security, security-roles, tivoli-identity-manager

I am new to ITIM. I am working on an application in JAVA. I want to authorize users based on groups they are assigned to. How can I do that?

Is there any api that can fetch user roles/groups by which I can authorize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system user will have an attribute of ‘erroles’ through which we can get information of user groups/Roles.

Get **DistinguishedName** from **Person** object. Make **PersonMO** object having constructor like `new PersonMO(platform, subject, person.getDistinguishedName());`

Make `new AccountManager(platform, subject);`

This will give accounts collection `accountManager.getAccounts(personMO, LocaleCreator.getLocale());`

Get **getSystemUserDN(userId);**. **PersonDao** class will help in getting this.

Make `new SystemUserMO(m_platform, m_subject, new DistinguishedName(systemUserDN));`

Get the roles/Groups from `systemUserMO.getData().getRoles()`

Cheers Imran Tariq